# Ionic 4: NFC can't import NFC and Ndef

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4

Starting a project in Ionic 4 with Cordova-plugins. I'm trying to initialize NFC into the project. I simply followed the Ionic documentation and the Cordova-Plugin is added into the package.json. Now I'm trying to add an NdefListener. So I can read, write and clear NFC tags.

I tried using @ionic-native/nfc instead of @ionic-native/nfc/ngx but my code won't find @ionic-native/nfc.

My Ionic CLI is 5.2.8 .

This is in my home.page.ts.

```js
import { NFC, Ndef } from "@ionic-native/nfc/ngx";

constructor(private nfc: NFC, private ndef: Ndef) {}
```

The error code I receive when only using ndef in the constructor no other code, same happens when I put NFC first only Ndef is changed into NFC.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomePage -> Ndef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HomePage -> Ndef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Ndef!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomePage -> Ndef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HomePage -> Ndef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Ndef!
    at NullInjector.get (/vendor-es2015.js:35988)
    at resolveToken (/vendor-es2015.js:37774)
    at tryResolveToken (/vendor-es2015.js:37700)
    at StaticInjector.get (/vendor-es2015.js:37563)
    at resolveToken (/vendor-es2015.js:37774)
    at tryResolveToken (/vendor-es2015.js:37700)
    at StaticInjector.get (/vendor-es2015.js:37563)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (/vendor-es2015.js:61613)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (/vendor-es2015.js:62701)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (/vendor-es2015.js:61613)
    at resolvePromise (/polyfills-es2015.js:3803)
    at resolvePromise (/polyfills-es2015.js:3760)
    at /polyfills-es2015.js:3864
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/polyfills-es2015.js:3397)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (/vendor-es2015.js:69392)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/polyfills-es2015.js:3396)
    at Zone.runTask (/polyfills-es2015.js:3174)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (/polyfills-es2015.js:3565)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use NFC in your app you will need to add the NFC to your app.module.ts providers:

Answer (score 6):

You should also import it in your main module:

```
....
import { NFC, Ndef } from "@ionic-native/nfc/ngx";

@NgModule({
  ....
  providers: [
    ......
    NFC,
    Ndef
  ]
....
```